# Can We build a search function using GeoExt?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geoext

Or do I need another technology?

I need to build a web gis server and I need map display, layers switch, search function and attribute display feature.

I am currently using GeoServer, OpenLayers and GeoExt.

Comment: May be, Please tell me. Can I use GeoEXT for map search feature and attribute display? I cant see such example on geoExt website.

Comment: I recommend that you edit your Question to focus on that precise question i.e. How to use GeoExt for map search feature and attribute display?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'search function' What exactly do you want to search? What source data do you have? These kinds of details will help in getting an answer.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Sir, I am using geoserver, and published data. Now I need a client GUI to display maps and search function, which can search the records and display results in a table and in between search records needs to be highlighted on map.

Comment: @AshutoshAgrawal It's still not clear what you mean by search. Do you need Auto Complete? Or a dropdown? Or do you need to search through an table which is being displayed? Or do you need to search for a particular keyword in all fields of all layers? The answer will be different for each case.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Sir, I need to search by a particular keyword, column specific is fine too. Suppose I enter unique id as search term, then map will be zoomed to that feature and other entries for that unique id should be displayed as in attribute table.

Comment: The sort answer is that it is possible with GeoExt. I'll suggest that you edit this question, and put in detailed information about what you want to achieve. That way this question will be put in the review queue, and there is a chance of someone answering it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, check [here](http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/apps/gaz/index.html) for an example using GeoExt, Geoserver and OpenLayers.

This is a discussion that may help you out in your search: [Search functionality in Openlayers/Geoserver](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11167/search-functionality-in-openlayers-geoserver)

It seems that Ian's link is broken, here you can do more or less the same but with GeoDjango: http://invisibleroads.com/tutorials/geodjango-googlemaps-build.html#id10

Comment: Link for site psu.edu is not working. Can you please provide me another link or you can email me tut on my email. ashutosh_agg@live.com

Comment: @iant <- he's the owner, the tutorial is in the link I provided before, hope he can upload it again. I updated my answer with a tutorial to do more or less the same thing but using GeoDjango.